# How can I restart the list inside of a word table using PowerShell?

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

So, I have been trying to iterate through a table in word, starting with the second row and 4th column. I created a macro in the document that restarts a list, "ListRestart_2023."

I tried the following and nothing happened

```
# Initialize Word application
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $True
Unblock-File "C:\temp\temp.docx"
$docDoc = $word.Documents.Open("C:\temp\temp.docx")
Write-Host "doc full name: " $docDoc.FullName

$docTable = $docDoc.Tables[3] 

for ($i = 2; $i -le $docTable.Rows.Count; $i++) {
    for ($j = 4; $j -le $docTable.Columns.Count; $j++) {
        $word.Application.Run("ListRestart_2023")
    }
}

#save and close the destination document
$docDoc.Save()
$docDoc.Close()

# Quit the Word application
$word.Quit()
```

Is there a better way to do this? I tried this too:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le $docTable.Rows.Count; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j -le $docTable.Columns.Count; $j++) {
        $listParagraphs = $docTable.Cell($i,$j).Range.ListParagraphs
        foreach($listParagraph in $listParagraphs)
        {
            $listParagraph.Range.ListFormat.RestartNumbering()
        }
    }
}
```

And this,

```
$docTable.Cell($i,$j).Range.ListFormat.RestartNumbering()
```

But, I haven't been able to get anything to happen.

Comment: `$listFormat = $docDoc.Tables[3].Cell(2,4).range.listformat; $listFormat.ApplyListTemplate($listFormat.listtemplate, $false)`  This will restart the numbering on cell row 2 column 4.

Comment: So, I tried that, but now I am getting "requested member of the collection does not exists,"  for the "$listFormat, = ,"and "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression," for the "$listFormat.Apply..."